# Doctrine2 and polimorphic relationship

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, polymorphic-associations

I have an entity called Document. I'd like to make this entity related (many to one) to few other entities (let's say User, Invoice and Transaction). In Laravel I could easily achieve that by using [polymorphic relations](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations). 
Is there any (easy) way to accomplish the same with Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: This is creating foreign keys in tables so cannot provide what I'm looking for...